# SQL Server 2008 R2 an error occurred during the installation of assembly

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 : an error occurred during the installation of assembly

Error installing SQL Server 2008 R2

> AN ERROR OCCURRED DURING THE INSTALLATION OF ASSEMBLY 'microsoft.vc80..crt.version="8.0.50727.1833", publickeytoken ="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" processorarchiteure="x86",type="win32"'.
>       please refer to help and support for more information.HRESULT:0X80070091

Error log

```
  Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052081
  Exit facility code:            1212
  Exit error code:               1935
  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Start time:                    2016-10-18 12:43:18
  End time:                      2016-10-18 12:54:56
  Requested action:              Install
  Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161018_124236\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  TU-KEPEGAWAIAN5
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  Installation location:         d:\3d266eac1900851510714b4790ad\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          EXPRESS

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       2

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      True
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CUSOURCE:                      
  ENABLERANU:                    True
  ENU:                           True
  ERRORREPORTING:                False
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    SQLExpress
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  PCUSOURCE:                     d:\3d266eac1900851510714b4790ad\PCUSOURCE
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           TU-KEPEGAWAIAN5\tu-kepegawaian5,BUILTIN\Administrators
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  False
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161018_124236\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161018_124236\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options for fixes/workarounds in these issue:

check below links.

[Error MS SQL : 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/72f27c30-5307-49e3-85dc-12a9c4704296/sql-server-2008-setup-failure-win-7-x64-msi-error-1935-an-error-occurred-during-the-installation)

[Error MS SQL : 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea68f38e-98d6-4e4e-ad3c-02538da68720/instalation-error)

also re install updated Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package.

Please let us know if you have any concerns.

Comment: ok first error no show again but next error , is not a valid login or you donot have permision.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same error IDs during installtion.
In my case the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)" was wrong, so i simply had to install the missing component and afterwards was able to install SQL Server without errors.
Just have a look here: https://cms4j.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/sql-server-2008-r2-installation-failed-2068052081-1212-1935

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same error for SQL Server 2014. I reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) and then it did not install again.

I disabled my antivirus and than reinstalled SQL Server and it is installed.